# CUDA inline PTX ld.shared runs into cudaErrorIllegalAddress error

Tags: cuda, inline, ptx, gpu-shared-memory

I'm using inline PTX `ld.shared` to load data from shared memory:

```
__shared__ float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];  //declare a buffer in shared memory
float Csub = 0;

As[TY][TX] = A[a + wA * TY + TX];             //load data from global memory to shared memory
__syncthreads();
float t;
asm("ld.shared.f32 %0, [%1];" :"=f"(t) : "r"((int)&As[TY][k]));  //load data from shared memory into t
Csub += t;
__syncthreads();
```

But it runs into an error:

```
CUDA error at C:/ProgramData/NVIDIA Corporation/CUDA Samples/v11.2/0_Simple/matrixMul_mine/matrixMul.cu:196 code=700(cudaErrorIllegalAddress) "cudaStreamSynchronize(stream)"
```

I dumped the SASS and found that the `LDS` happens even earlier than `LDG` and the two `bar.sync` instructions. It seems that the compiler looses track of the data dependency.

So my questions are:

1. Is there anything wrong in my inline PTX that leads to `cudaErrorIllegalAddress`?
2. Does inline PTX disturb the compilers ability to track data dependencies?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html#incorrect-optimization

Comment: Perhaps you also have to declare As as volatile in addition to talonmies answer, the illegal address probably is independent from the order - but we cannot see where your parameters a, wA, TY, TK, k are coming from, how large the global array is or with what block and grid size your kernel is called.

Comment: Just learnt that the address need to be converted by "cvta" like [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass/blob/6fc5008803fe4e81b81a836fcd3a88258f4e5bbf/include/cutlass/arch/memory_sm75.h#L90) in cutlass. And as Sebastian said, 'volatile' should be added right after 'asm'.

Answer (score 4):

Yichen's comment is right.

There are two types of addressing: `ld.` or `ld.statespace`.

If `ld.` is used on its own, the address should be a generic address. The generic address, to my limited understanding, is the CUDA-C++ pointer value, like `&As[TY][k]` in your code.

If `ld.statespace` is used, the address should be the address in the state space.

I think if you use `ld.f32` instead of `ld.shared.f32`, your code should be okay. BTW, I don't think you can use the generic address in 32-bit data width, which can truncate the generic address into a wrong value.

Or you can convert the generic address to the shared space address. Here is [CUTLASS](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cutlass)' conversion code:

```
      ".reg .u32 smem_ptr32;\n\t"
      ".reg .u64 smem_ptr64; cvta.to.shared.u64 smem_ptr64, %1; cvt.u32.u64 smem_ptr32, smem_ptr64; \n\t"
```

Then use `smem_ptr32` instead of `[%1]`:

```
"ld.shared.f32 %0, [smem_ptr32];"
```

As the PTX ISA says, this address can be either 32-bit or 64-bit. I think it's not necessary to convert the 64-bit pointer to a 32-bit pointer. Using `smem_ptr64` should be okay.

Here is what the shared memory address could look like:

| Pointer | State Space | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUDA-C++ pointer | Generic Space | `1526743433216 + 1024` |
| `smem_ptr64` | Shared Space | `0 + 1024` |